# Create views programmatically using XML on Android

Tags: android, xml

I want to create a UI layout in XML and have it inserted as a child into an existing view (It will be inserted multiple times).

For example, here is what the XML file will contain:

```xml
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" >
    <Button android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:text="@string/mystring" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now I get the parent `LinearLayout` and now want to add that XML file as a child view, e.g:

```java
LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLayout);

// need to create a view object from the xml file
linear.addView(myXmlObject);
```

Is it possible to convert an XML resource to a view type? If so, how would I do this?

Comment: @Eric Oh wow, I missed that. But wait!

Comment: @Sam How did I even... I just... okay, you completely owned me there.

Comment: It feels to me like you you should probably looking for an Adapter of some sort.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

I believe you want the [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html). Let's say your example XML is in a file `custom_layout.xml`:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null, false);

LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
linear.addView(layout);
```

Comment: Thanks dude. you saved my time

Comment: How did you handle the button click? I mean each row's button click has a different function.